# Insert a single Table into Multiple Databases

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert a table into multiple databases.
I have figured out how to make it insert the single table into all of the Databases but I need it to exclude about 10 databases like the master, model, tempdb, msdb, then I have some others as well.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb    
'    
USE ?;
IF [?] NOT IN master, model, tempdb,    
 CREATE TABLE [?].[dbo].[FaceEnrollments](
    [EmployeeNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TIN] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [irFaceTemplate] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [faceBitmap] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [faceAttestationAccepted] [bit] NULL,
    [EnrollmentDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FaceEnrollments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [EmployeeNo] ASC,
    [TIN] ASC
)
);
';
```

This is what I got so far to add the table to all databases.
I have tried multiple things to exclude databases from this, but I cannot figure it out.
I was hoping someone could help me out. Please and Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adjust your dynamic query to this:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb

'
IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''model'', ''tempdb'')
 CREATE TABLE ?.[dbo].[FaceEnrollments](
    [EmployeeNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TIN] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [irFaceTemplate] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [faceBitmap] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [faceAttestationAccepted] [bit] NULL,
    [EnrollmentDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FaceEnrollments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [EmployeeNo] ASC,
    [TIN] ASC
)
);
';
```

Also I recommand the better and more flexible sp originally created by Aaron Bertrand, you can download from Github for free :
 [SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/sp_ineachdb](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql)
which you can use exclude_list or exclude_pattern parameter to exclude databases:

```
exec [dbo].[sp_ineachdb] 
     @exclude_list = 'List of excluded databases'
     @command = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FaceEnrollments](...)'
```

Comment: I did try the above code earlier this morning when I did some research I saw you could do the:
IF [?] NOT IN thing, but I was unable to make this work.
Even if I use your code it still does not work for me.
IF ''?'' NOT IN (<master, model, tempdb>)
 CREATE TABLE ?.[dbo].[FaceEnrollments]

The error ends up coming out as:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '?'.

Comment: the database names should be enclosed by single quote , because you want to compare them as string , see updated answer, but why not using Aaron's proc ? it's much easier to use that proc .

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That did work for me. Then to answer your question about why I did not use the script. If I am being completely honest last night was the first time I had ever tried to do anything like this in SQL and I honestly don't have a clue how to install the script or go about using it. I did add his github to my notes and I will be looking into it as I think I will be doing a lot more SQL related things in the future. Thank you again!

Comment: you are welcome , and this was just a stored proc. you could just run that sql script on your master db .

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I will give it a try on my VM! Thank you again!